# How to have below method as static in an interface with no body

Tags: java, interface

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.List;

public interface EmployeeServ {

@POST
@Path("/v1/employees/xdata/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Response updateReport(List<String> request, String id);

}
```

So this method doesn't need a body because all the annotations are doing the needful.
Is there anyway I can make this method static/default?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

Methods without any body are `abstract`. All methods of an interface without any body are `public abstract` implicitly.

`static` and `default` methods can not be `abstract` therefore you can not make your method `static` or `default`.